# Only Owner of the Profile able to Update the data

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-views

Using class Based (APIView) in Django rest framework for Getting and Patch (Updating) UserInfo data.

**views.py**

```
class getUserInfo(APIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        user = request.user
        userinfos = user.userinfo_set.all()
        serializer = UserInfoSerializers(userinfos, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def patch(self, request, pk, format=None):
        user = UserInfo.objects.get(id=pk)
        serializer = UserInfoSerializers(instance=user, data=request.data, partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**serializers.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import UserInfo

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'username')

class UserInfoSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(many=False, required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = UserInfo
        fields = ('id', 'picture', 'profession', 'user')
```

Everything is working so far so good. Able to GET and PATCH (Update) logged-in user data.
While Testing the API in Postman, I found out that if User1 is logged in he can change the data of User2 by only using the pk of User2.

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('userinfo/', views.getUserInfo.as_view(), name="UserInfo"),
    path('userinfo/<str:pk>/', views.getUserInfo.as_view()),
    path('api/token/', views.MyTokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('api/token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
    path('register/', views.RegisterView.as_view(), name='auth_register'),
]
```

*Using rest_framework_simplejwt for Auth*

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to="profile_pics", null=True)
    profession = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s's Profile Picture" % self.user
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the primary key to get the user.You are using `user = request.user` to get the user on **get** method, use the same mechanism also on **update**. Then the login user can only update his/her info not others info or another way you can check the  `user = UserInfo.objects.get(id=pk)` is same as the current user `request.user` . If not you can show an exception.

Answer (score 0):

For Retrieving and Updating an object, you can use `RetrieveUpdateAPIView`

```
class GetUserInfo(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = UserInfo.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserInfoSerializers
    
    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user
```

Here we are getting an object, it will be called from `get_object` method. Instead of getting user using PK, we get the current user.

You can use same url for getting and updating the user, just change the method in postman while you hit the api. GET for retrieving and PATCH for partial update.

`path('userinfo/', views.GetUserInfo.as_view(), name="UserInfo"),`